# How to change the array of decimal numbers to hex?

Tags: c

So far I have this , I am trying to convert these decimal numbers to hex numbers and then use fwrite() function to write it into the file. Can someone help please ?

```
struct tm* tm_info;
char day[2];
char month[2];
char year[4];
char hour[2];
char min[2];
char sec [2];
char weekday[2];
time(&timer);
tm_info = localtime(&timer);
unsigned short ab= strftime(day, 2, "%d", tm_info);
unsigned short bc= strftime(month, 2, "%m", tm_info);
unsigned short cd= strftime(year, 4, "%Y", tm_info);
unsigned short de= strftime(hour, 2, "%H", tm_info);
unsigned short ef= strftime(min, 2, "%M", tm_info);
unsigned short gh= strftime(sec, 2, "%S", tm_info);
```

Comment: All your strings forget about the terminating null character and should be 1 larger.

Comment: All the values in `tm_info` are integer vaues and so are stored in bits and are already hexadecimal. Lookup `struct tm` in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> to convert these decimal numbers to hex numbers and then use fwrite() function to write it into the file.

Get time info

```
time(&timer);
struct tm* tm_info = localtime(&timer);
```

Let us try solving this for 1 part of time - month

```
// Do not hard code 2, use the size of the array
// size_t strftime(char *s, size_t maxsize, const char *format, const struct tm *timeptr)
//   forms a _string_ at s.  Make the buffer large enough for a conversion of any `int`.
//   No reason to be stingy here. 
//   Let us assume a worst case of a 64-bit int which needs 21 char printed as a string.
// strftime() returns 
//   "total number of resulting characters including the terminating null character"
//    or zero on error.  Useful for error checking.
// unsigned short bc= strftime(month, 2, "%m", tm_info);
char ibuffer[21];
if (strftime(ibuffer, sizeof ibuffer, "%m", tm_info) > 0) {
  // Success
```

Convert *string* `ibuffer` to an `unsigned`.

```
  unsigned value = atoi(ibuffer);
```

Write `value` as text to `month`.  Pad with leading `'0'` and insure code stays within `month[]`.

```
  char month[2];
  snprintf(month, sizeof month, "%02X", value);
```

Write to a file

```
  fwrite(month, sizeof month, 1, out_stream);
```

---

No need to go through `strftime()`.  Simply read, and perhaps offset, the various `struct tm` members.

```
  char month[2];
  snprintf(month, sizeof month, "%02X", tm_info->tm_mon + 1u);
  fwrite(month, sizeof month, 1, out_stream);
```